# Why doesn't fifty-five equal thirty-six?

Tags: support

What explains the discrepancy between the "number of posts awaiting review" highlighted in the header of the site, and the number of posts I actually see for review across all queues I have access to?

[image: Screenshot of EL&U showing review queue discrepancies]

At first I thought it was just a synchronization or lag thing, but the header number is consistently higher than the sum of posts in the review queues.  I then thought maybe it has something to do with other stacks I'm subscribed to, but currently EL&U is the only stack where I've earned reviewing privileges.

There's not even anything in the Meta.ELU review queue that could be contributing to the total count. The only other thing I can think of which could explain the discrepancy is the 55 includes items for review in queues which I don't have access to yet (say, the delete queues).

Can anyone shed some light? Or should I be asking this on Meta.StackExchange?

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238698/does-the-review-queue-page-show-only-reviews-requiring-your-action-does-it-diff/238699#238699

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The difference is (what needs to be done on the site) - (what you can do).

When an item in the queue (e.g. closing a question) needs more than one vote to be completed, you can only contribute a fraction of what's needed to get the item off the review queue. That's multiplied by six for six review queues. While you may have voted on every item, the number of items left for the remaining votes is still high.

So... it takes a village to clear the queues.

Comment: While I am sure this is correct, the tooltip actually says "X total posts awaiting review", which is misleading at best.